# java.lang.NullPointerException at Runtime in VideoListFragment

Tags: android, stack-trace

I am getting a runtime exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment.onCreateView(VideoListFragment.java at Line 113)

**StackTrace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1545): Process: com.loco.android, PID: 1545
E/AndroidRuntime(1545): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment.onCreateView(VideoListFragment.java:113)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDITED:**

**VideoListFragment.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.frgment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

    OnVideoSelectedListener mCallback;
    boolean loadingMore = false;

    // create string variables
    String YOUTUBE_USERNAME = "";

    private String YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
            "&v=2"+
            "&start-index=1"+
            "&max-results=10";

    // create object of views
    ListView list;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    Button btnRefresh;
    Button btnLoadMore;

    // create variable to get position, connection status, resources, and channel username
    int position;
    boolean isConnect = true;
    Resources res;
    String[] ChannelUsername;

    // create object of custom adapter
    VideoListAdapter vla;

    // create arraylist variables
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // flag for current page
    int current_page = 1;
    int previous_page;

    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

    // create interface listener
    public interface OnVideoSelectedListener{
        public void onVideoSelected(String ID);
    }

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

            list = (ListView)view .findViewById(R.id.list);
            btnRefresh = (Button)view .findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);

        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // get value that passed from previous page
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        position = bundle.getInt("position", 0); 

        // get channel username and put selected channel to youtube api
        res = getActivity().getResources();  ---->Error at Line 113
        ChannelUsername = res.getStringArray(R.array.channel_username);
        YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];

        YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
                "&v=2"+
                "&start-index=1"+
                "&max-results=10";

        // create LoadMore button
        btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
        btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_light);
        btnLoadMore.setText(getString(R.string.load_more));

        // adding load more button to lisview at bottom
        list.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

        new loadFirstListView().execute();

        // listener to handle load more buttton when clicked
        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Starting a new async task
                isConnect = true;
                new loadMoreListView().execute();
            }
        });



        // listener to handle list when clicked
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item = menuItems.get(position);

                mCallback.onVideoSelected(item.get("id"));

                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
        });

        // listener to handle refresh button when clicked
        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isConnect = true;
                new loadFirstListView().execute();
            }
        });
        return view;        
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        vla.imageLoader.clearCache();
        Log.d("clear cache", "clear cache");
    }


}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loco.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
        android:name="com.sit.loco.app.GemsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.MenuActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.HomeActivity" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.GalleryActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.AnnouncementActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.BlogActivity" >
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.DownloadActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.PlayerActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I didn't know how to solve this.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Which line is 113 in `VideoListFragment` and why your title talk about NoClassDefFounrError?

Comment: @Jens I mentioned that in coding `position = bundle.getInt("position", 0);`

Comment: Where is the method `getArguments();` defined?

Comment: @Jens That wasn't defined anywhere.Then what to do?

Comment: But you call it `Bundle bundle = getArguments();` if it is not defined it will not compile?

Comment: @Jens No it was successfully compiled.I am getting errors at runtime

Comment: Can you verify if `getArguments();` returns a value different from null?

Comment: @Naruto : You are overriding the `setArguments(...)` method of your `Fragment` but it does absolutely nothing. Assuming you are creating an instance of the `Fragment` in your `Activity` then any call to `getArguments(....)` will *ALWAYS* return `null`. Delete the `setArguments(...)` method from your `Fragment` code. Also, delete the `getSupportActivity()` method from your `Fragment` - that also serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
res = getSupportActivity().getResources();
```

to

```
res = getActivity().getResources();
```

Because `getSupportActivity()` return **null**

Comment: If I done that I am getting a null pointer exception at that same line

Comment: @Naruto Same line means `bundle` line or `getActivity()` line.

Answer (score 0):

Error is NoClassDefFoundException it means compiler unable to find your class

so you need to mention this class perfectly as per my undestanding you are using library for this project if yes then follow below step to resolve error of "NoClassDefFoundException"

1 ) Right click on project

2) goto properties

3) goto java build path

4) goto order and export tab

5) check in library which you include for your project

6) click ok apply the changes and compile your code

hope it will work for you